# Exporting GUIDs to a text file in non-unicode

Tags: ssis

I'm exporting data from a MS Dynamics CRM 2011 database table to a text file. Initially I was just exporting string data - i.e. columns defined as nvarchar, and it worked fine. However when I added the primary key column - uniqueidentifier/guid, SSIS just outputs unicode to the text file.

I'm explicitly casting all columns in my SQL query to VARCHAR, and have ensured all the source/destination columns are defined as non-unicode strings i.e. DT_STR, but still get unicode in the file.

Funnily enough this only happens when I run the SSIS package on our server which has SSIS 2008/Windows 2008 Server 64-bit. Our database is SQL 2008 64-bit as well, also on a seperate Windows 2008 server. The package works fine on my PC - Win7 64-bit.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the bcp utility for your export.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

“The bcp utility bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and a data file in a user-specified format”

The –N argument is documented as “Performs the bulk-copy operation using the native (database) data types of the data for noncharacter data, and Unicode characters for character data.” Which implies that by omitting this arg you will not get Unicode in the output.